# How to check for this Date Time Pattern if some minutes are over for Java Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetime-comparison

I receive this Date Time pattern from Server as a string.

> Sa. 07.01.2023 16:39:15

Now i want to check if 1 minute is over.
Like if the gap between the current time and the time (received as a string) from server is
longer than a minute.

The time zone is in Europe. Like Austria.

Comment: Do we know in which time zone that string was created? Depending on time zone it may denote a time within a span of some 26 hours.

Comment: The time zone is in Europe. Like Austria

Comment: How would you do that if you tell you a time and you're supposed to check if a certain amount of minutes as passed? I guess you would "parse" my information as a datetime and then compare the time difference with "now()"? Java/Android can do that as well and those steps are researchable. Have you done some research? Tried anything?

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("Sa. 07.01.2023 16:39:15", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E dd.MM.uuuu H:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN)) .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) .plusMinutes(1) .isBefore(ZonedDateTime.now())`.

Comment: Or instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`  we need to give `ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna")` if you know that this is the server’s time zone.

Comment: it allways shows false

Comment: Weird. It produces `true` on my Java 18. Happy that you accepted the answer, though. I take it to mean you got your question answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Parse the given date-time string into a `LocalDateTime`.
2. Convert the obtained `LocalDateTime` into a `ZonedDateTime` by applying a `ZoneId`.
3. Get the current `ZonedDateTime` in the applied `ZoneId`.
4. Finally, find the minutes between the current `ZonedDateTime` and the `ZonedDateTime` obtained from the date-time string.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Sa. 07.01.2023 16:39:15";

        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN);

        // Note: change the ZoneId as per your requirement

        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parser)
                                         .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna"));
        System.out.println("Date-time received from the server: " + zdt);

        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zdt.getZone());
        System.out.println("Current date-time: " + now);

        System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(zdt, now) > 1);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run**:

```
Date-time received from the server: 2023-01-07T16:39:15+01:00[Europe/Vienna]
Current date-time: 2023-01-07T17:33:04.140599+01:00[Europe/Vienna]
true
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/o0ChQR)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

Incorporating the following valuable alternative solution [suggested by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75041789/how-to-check-for-this-date-time-pattern-if-some-minutes-are-over-for-java-androi/75041882#comment132426811_75041882):

> Might be more clear if you switch to `Instant` objects at the end.
> Extract an `Instant` from your first `ZonedDateTime`, and change
> `ZonedDateTime now` to `Instant now`.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Sa. 07.01.2023 16:39:15";

        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN);

        // Note: change the ZoneId as per your requirement

        Instant instantParsed = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parser)
                                             .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna"))
                                             .toInstant();
        System.out.println("Instant received from the server: " + instantParsed);

        Instant instantNow = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("Current instant: " + instantNow);

        System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(instantParsed, instantNow) > 1);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/KUFq0c)

Comment: the time zone can be different. people from all over the world have access. its only for their current time zone. it can be everywhere

Comment: @DealZg - If your use case is to find the difference between the date-times ignoring the timezone, you can find the difference between the parsed string (i.e. `LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parser)`) and `LocalDateTime.now()`. Please keep in mind that the current date-time in America is different from the current date-time in Austria. So, most use cases are to compare the date-times at the same timezone.

Comment: Might be more clear if you switch to `Instant` objects at the end. Extract an `Instant` from your first `ZonedDateTime`, and change  `ZonedDateTime now` to `Instant now`.